# Get-WinEventでIPアドレス指定だとエラーになってしまう

Tags: windows, powershell

PowerShellを用いて、他のマシンのイベントログを `Get-WinEvent` で取得しようとしています。

`ComputerName` オプションの引数にマシン名を指定すると正常に取得できるのですが、同一マシンに対してIPアドレス指定で取得しようとすると、以下のエラーが発生します。

```
Get-WinEvent : 許可されていない操作を実行しようとしました。
発生場所 行:1 文字:1
+ Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $server -Credential $credential -FilterHas ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WinEvent], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand
```

エラーの原因、解決方法はありますでしょうか。

Comment: 別のコマンドですが、もしかしたらこんな記事が参考になるかも？ [PowerShellでリモートのイベントログを取得する（その２）](http://kazemati.blogspot.com/2010/05/powershell.html)

Comment: 実は紹介いただいた記事は拝見してまして、NET USEは別扱いになるため成功しないと認識しています。